# Can I avoid sql injection in sqlite fts replacing quotes?

Tags: sql, sqlite, boost, sql-injection

Here is my sql in cpp:

```
boost::format("select Rowid from Name where Idx match '%s'") % key
```

Is it safe to prevent injection by filtering quotation marks?

```
exmaple:
key : "ab'c" -> "ab''c" 
key : "a\"b'c" -> "a\"\"b'c"
```

Comment: What is sqlite fts?

Comment: Alternatively use the bind_XXX functions https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html